# Glitching normal map artifacts

Tags: normals, baking, normal-map

I'm getting strange artifacts in my normal map as you can see from the photos. Yes, I've checked all the normals and recalculated them several times. Yes, I have removed all doubles. Yes, All scale/transforms are reset. Yes, no other objects are overlapping. Yes, The object is large enough where it wont effect baking. Yes, I've tried baking both tangent and object space. I'm out of ideas, I am using Blender 2.81.[image]

Comment: It looks like there are overlapping faces. This can be within one object.

Comment: The object in the photo is the high & low poly on top of each other, I can give the .blend if you would like to try it?

Comment: No, thanks. I know almost nothing about baking.

Answer (score 0):

The ray distance has to be non-zero, increase it to avoid the problem.

Comment: Maybe give a how-to screenshot.